# JQuery append function works offline but does not work online

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am creating an text based game with js.It works just fine when I run it locally but when I upload it to my server and run it nothing shows up.There is something I am missing.It might be about the "append" but I am not sure.Can you tell me what is causing this problem. Thanks in advance.

The code:

```
var currentRoom = "start";
var commands = ["go", "pickup", "inventory", "talk",];
var inventory = ["sword", "shield"];

function changeRoom(dir) {
    if (rooms[currentRoom].directions[dir] !== undefined) {
        currentRoom = rooms[currentRoom].directions[dir]
        $('#game-text').append("<p>" + rooms[currentRoom].description + "</p>");
    } else {
        $('#game-text').append("<p>You cannot go that way!</p>");
    }


}

function showHelp() {
    $('#game-text').append("<p>Here are the possible commands: </p>");
    $('#game-text').append("<p><ul>");
    for (var i = 0; i < commands.length; i++) {
        $('#game-text').append("<li>" + commands[i] + "</li>");
    }
    $('#game-text').append("</ul></p>");

}

function showInventory() {
    if (inventory.length === 0) {
        $('#game-text').append("<p>You are not carrying anything!</p>");
        return;
    }
    $('#game-text').append("<p>Here is your inventory: </p>");
    $('#game-text').append("<p><ul>");
    for (var i = 0; i < inventory.length; i++) {
        $('#game-text').append("<li>" + inventory[i] + "</li>");
    }
    $('#game-text').append("</ul></p>");

}

function playerInput(input) {
    var command = input.split(" ")[0];
    switch (command) {
        case "go":
            var dir = input.split(" ")[1];
            changeRoom(dir);
            break;
        case "help":
            showHelp();
            break;
        case "inventory":
            showInventory();
            break;
        default:
            $('#game-text').append("<p>Invalid command!</p>");
    }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#game-text').append("<p>" + rooms.start.description + "</p>");

      $(document).keypress(function(key){
        if (key.which === 13 && $('#user-input').is(':focus')) {
            var value = $('#user-input').val().toLowerCase();
            $('#user-input').val("");
            playerInput(value);
        }
    })
```

})

html:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Androideas</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">

</head>
<body>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="rooms.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
  <div id="game-text" style="color:white;">
         <p>Welcome to Zork!</p>
     </div>


<input id="user-input" placeholder="Please type your command..."></input>

</body>





</html>
```

rooms.js file:

```
var rooms = {
    "start": {
        "description": "You are in a dark, cold place and you see a light to <b>north</b>\
     and you hear the sound of running water to the <b>west</b>",
        "directions": {
            "north": "clearing1",
            "west": "bridge1"
        }
    },
    "clearing1": {
        "description": "You arrive to a clearing, you see a lighthouse to the <b>north</b>\
     and there is a strange smell coming from the <b>east</b>",
        "directions": {
            "south": "start",
            "north": "lighthouse",
            "east": "trolls"
        }
    },
    "lighthouse": {
        "description": "You arrive to the lighthouse and walk up to the door. A strange old lady\
     opens the door. What do you do?",
        "directions": {
            "south": "clearing1"
        }
    },
    "trolls": {
        "description": "You arrive to another clearing, there are some trolls roasting some mysterious meat\
     They haven't seen you yet. What do you do?",
        "directions": {
            "west": "clearing1"
        }
    },
    "bridge1": {
        "description": "You see a river and there is a bridge to the <b>west</b>",
        "directions": {
            "east": "start",
            "west": "bridge2"
        }
    },
    "bridge2": {
        "description": "You try to cross the bridge but a troll jumps out and bites your leg!",
        "directions": {
            "east": "bridge1"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Check the console for errors. If the code works locally but not after being uploaded to your server it's most likely a path issue.

Comment: yesterday I checked the console at least 5 times but there were nothing and now it says "uncaught syntax error: unexpected token )"

Comment: That's the problem then :) If you double click the error it will take you to the offending line

Comment: I uploaded the fixed version to the server but console stil shows the old code.I uploaded it a couple of times but it still did not fix it